# 404 "customer/ajax/login" in checkout login magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, login

In the checkout after put my email (Or put an email already registered) and put my password and click on enter, I can't login or keep going with the checkout for obvious reasons, it shows the loading gif and then stop.

After stop, the console show the following message: `"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"`

The 404 say: `login:1 which is -> (/customer/ajax/login)`

I already verified my permissions and everything else is working perfectly, I already generated all the files with setup:di:compile and setup:static-content:deploy as well

My Magento version is 2.4.3, if there's any solution, either to disable the login in the checkout or solving it directly, please tell me.

Comment: Have you used custom module on this ?

Comment: @クジェー no, i've updated to the latest version of my theme which is claue from mgs and the issue remains. In fact, the authentication.phtml of the theme does not have any modification similar to the login